# Solving nonlinear systems involving trigonometric functions

Tags: equation-solving

EDIT 1/2:

["hardest?" geometry problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521825/the-hardest-geometry-question-with-a-triangle-and-a-circle-circle-intersec)

Triangle and sector areas are relatively easy to compute, first a numerical solution is attempted. For this interesting computation I intend giving this website link when done on `Mathematica`, i.e., if already not closed.

[image]

As a first step to solve this problem, shown  partitioned regions of unit circle colored (light blue, yellow, pink,  mixed)  labeled $ (B,A=A1+A2+A3,CC,D)$ in half of the figure are considered. The scaled regions measure $\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}$ respectively.

$$B: \dfrac{\alpha}{2 }\cdot 1^2 - \dfrac{\pi}{2}\sin \alpha \cos \alpha$$
$$A : \dfrac{1}{2}\sin \alpha \cos \alpha + \dfrac{\beta}{2 \pi}+ \dfrac{ u}{2} \cdot \sin(\alpha+\beta)$$

$$ CC: \frac{\pi-\alpha -\beta}{2 \pi} - \frac{ u }{2}\cdot \sin(\alpha+\beta)$$

> ```
> Clear["Global`*"]
>
> B[al_] = al/(2  Pi) - Cos[al] Sin[al]/2.
> A[al_, bt_, u_] = Cos[al] Sin[al]/2 + bt/(2.  Pi) + u/2 Sin[al + bt]
> CC[al_, bt_, u_] = (Pi - al - bt)/(2 Pi) - u/2*Sin[al + bt]
>
> Solve[{ B[al] == 1/6, A[al, bt, u] == 1/6, CC[al, bt, u] == 1/6},
>       { al, bt, u}, Reals, Method -> Reduce]
> ```

(After scaling changes and `Reduce` suggested by Artes)

There was no diagnostic to find error. Also could not `Flatten` either side properly.

Please help to obtain a solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get both errors and solutions in V13.1.

Comment: Why do you have `2.` instead of `2` in  three places?

Comment: Thanks. Before upgrading any  work around solution?

Comment: @Syed: I thought it would give a numerical solution at first.

Comment: I get a warning about machine precision input, and solutions, in v. 12.3.1 on Win10-64

Comment: Try `Solve` instead of `NSolve`.

Comment: In my V8 still no solution

Comment: Use `Reduce` or with `Solve` use the option `Method -> Reduce`

Comment: Did not work after editing you suggested.

Comment: To closevoters.  Could you explain why this question should be closed?  I find no reason for it.

Comment: @MarcoB Perhaps you can  make me understand why closing?

Comment: @Artes I voted to close because I could not reproduce the described behavior with the code included.

Comment: @MarcoB Indeed the OP hasn't been clear (and it still is not quite clear), however under the scene there is a resonable core what can be deduced from the comments and answer.

Comment: @ Artes: Thanks for your answer. Apologies, there has been a scaling error so far unnoticed (by all?). Hope it is clearer now.  Edited to show area partitions. Feel free to point out if any error still remains.

Comment: Also $\alpha=1.44333, \beta$ is Complex infinity and $u$ is indeterminate with changes you suggested.

Comment: @Narasimham  Your question isn't still clear. You should rewrite it from scratch.  Whoever will read it should have a clear idea what is the problem (let's say a mathematical problem) and what is its Mathematica layer. This question is not only for you but for the whole community and whoever takes a look at it should have a feeling that the author treats readers seriously providing appropriate order of reasoning.  No one wants to lose his own time suspecting correct sense of the problem. It's  dissapointing that your interest in mathematics doesn't come together with clarity of thoughts.

Answer (score 6):

It is a good custom to define functions with `SetDelayed`, moreover one prefares possibly succinct names for independent variables, e.g. `α` and `β`instead of `al` and `bt` respectively. When we are looking for exact solutions we should use exact numbers instead of approximate ones. I'd mention that it is better not to use capital letters as names of functions, but that's enough, we hold them as proposed.

```
B[α_] := α/(2 π) - Cos[α] Sin[α]/2
A[α_, β_, u_] := Cos[α] Sin[α]/2 + β/(2 π) + u/2 Sin[α + β]
CC[α_, β_, u_] := (π - α - β)/(2 π) - u/2 Sin[α + β]
```

Now we can see that definitions imply

```
A[α, β, u] + B[α] + CC[α, β, u] // Simplify
```

> ```
> 1/2
> ```

what can be regarded as a solvability condition for the system `{A[α, β, u] == π/10, B[α] == π/10, CC[α, β, u] == π/10}`, and so it is contradictory and has no solutions since the rhs of `A[α, β, u] + B[α] + CC[α, β, u]` is `3 π/10 != 1/2`.
This can be found e.g. with:

```
Reduce[{B[α] == π/10, A[α, β, u] == π/10, CC[α, β, u] == π/10}, {α, β, u}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

The comments suggest that there were numerical solutions, however there are none what can be observed e.g. with

```
NMinimize[ Norm[{A[α, β, u] - π/10, B[α] - π/10, CC[α, β, u] - π/10}],
           {α, β, u}]
```

> ```
> {0.257904, {α -> -0.623425, β -> 2.22917, u -> 0.126727}}
> ```

Since the minimized norm is rather small this justifies why there were numerical "solutions" with appropriate warnings.

If we modify the system to be compatibile with the solvability condition we could find solutions. It might be neccessary to restrict variables to the real domain.

**Edit**

After **substantial change of the original question** we can see that it is reasonable to supplement the system with the following conditions `0 < α < π/2` and `0 < β < π` and now we can find solutions easily

```
Reduce[{ B[α] == 1/6, A[α, β, u] == 1/6, CC[α, β, u] == 1/6, 
         0 < α < π/2, 0 < β < π}, {α, β, u}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

`Solve` works similarily.
The freedom of choice of `β` comes from the origin of the problem. We can prescribe it to get specific angles, e.g.

```
With[{ β = π/12}, 
     Reduce[{ B[α] == 1/6, A[α, β, u] == 1/6, CC[ α, β, u] == 1/6, 
              0 < α < π/2}, { α, u}]] // N
```

> ```
> α == 1.44333 && u == 0.125034
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found that we only need to change the equation from `{B[al] == 1/6, A[al, bt, u] == 1/6, CC[al, bt, u] == 1/6}` to

```
B[al] == A[al, bt, u] == CC[al, bt, u]
```

```
Clear[B,A,CC];
B[al_] = al/(2 Pi) - Cos[al] Sin[al]/2;
A[al_, bt_, u_] = Cos[al] Sin[al]/2 + bt/(2 Pi) + u/2 Sin[al + bt];
CC[al_, bt_, u_] = (Pi - al - bt)/(2 Pi) - u/2*Sin[al + bt];

Reduce[{B[al] == A[al, bt, u] == CC[al, bt, u]}, {al, bt, u}, Reals]
```

[image]

Comment: Your change of the equations `{B[al] == 1/6, A[al, bt, u] == 1/6, CC[al, bt, u] == 1/6}` to `B[al] == A[al, bt, u] == CC[al, bt, u]` doesn't affect anything since $A+B+C=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Artes It means that we need not use the above relation. The above is only a extra equation. Pleae see my  edition history.